# I can't read the line I want in the file in C

Tags: c

I want to put the line I want into an array using file reading functions in C programming language and use that array in my code. But the code I wrote below cannot perform this operation. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("line.txt", "r");
    
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("FILE OPEN ERROR");
        return 1;
    }
    
    char line[200];
    
    while(fgets(line, 200, file) != '\0')
    {
        if(line[0] == 1)
        {
            printf("%s", fgets(line, 200, file));
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
    
    
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to check for with `line[0] == 1`?

Comment: What are the file contents, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Bonus questions to contemplate: [what does fgets return](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), what does `while` do (while file==NULL?)

Comment: I wrote the number of lines in front of the lines in the file. @JoachimSauer

Comment: There is a line number in front of each line, and I want to read the line I want from the file and throw it into an array. @teapot418

Comment: Are you aware that `line[0] == 1` actually searches the character Ctrl+A? If you want to search for the character 1, you'd better use `line[0] == '1'`. But beware you will also get 10, 11, etc.

Comment: You can remove `!= '\0'` from your read-loop test as `fgets()` will return `NULL` on failure. Using the *nul-character* is an odd condition to test for and I'm not sure that will have the desired effect across all implementations.

Answer (score 2):

`if(line[0] == 1)` tests if `line[0]` is the ASCII character Ctrl-A.

To check if the line begins with the character `'1'`:

```
if(line[0] == '1')
```

---

To print the line that meets the test:

```
 printf("%s", line);
```

To print the *next* line :

```
if (fgets(line, 200, file)) {
  printf("%s", line);
}
```